# NetSuite Advanced PDF - Filter the item table list using multiselect field on record

Tags: netsuite, freemarker, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Hope you can assist. I am currently working on an advanced PDF template, which filters the item table based on values selected on the multiselect field on the sales order.

Here is my attempt, which keeps throwing an unexpected error:

[image: adding extra #LIST in code]

Refer to the yellow highlights in the code. All works fine when I remove these.

If I understand correctly, multiselect values return an array; thus I should in theory be able to use the '#LIST' directive.

To explain the code briefly, I am trying to:

- loop each value found in multiselect field.
- compare this value to each column field in the second loop.
- if both values match, print the row, otherwise skip.

Any ideas or suggestions is most appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Please always include the exception message!

Comment: Unfortunately, the error is "unexpected error"!

Comment: Ugh. It's rather hard to work with template if you can't see the actual error message. Are you sure you can't get it from anywhere? Like you have access to the logs maybe? Anyway... a dirty trick. Put your template inside this `<#attempt>... your template here ...<#recover>FAILED:<pre>${.error}</pre></#attempt>`. Then the output of the template will contain the error message.

Comment: Apologies for delay. Unfortunately, even with the trick you have shared, I still receive the "unexpected error" when clicking the print button on the work order form. Would you know how to check the multiselect field is indeed being recognised as a "sequence" so it can be used correctly in the <#list> directive?

Comment: That #attempt doesn't work probably means that the template has some syntactical error and so execution can't even start. Can you try that on https://try.freemarker.apache.org? To test if something is a sequence: `${something?is_sequence?c}`. (Or probably you actually want `${something?is_enumerable?c}`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer to this. Hopefully this will help others.

Here are the changes I made to filter from a multi-select list:

[image]

I first assigned the multi-select field with "?word_list". This outputted the entire multi-select field as an array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

I then used this in the 'list' directive, and lastly ensured each value in the sequence was a string, so it can be compared with another string variable.